# Generating documentation using TypeLite

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, typelite

Is it possible to configure TypeLite to replicate documentation from the source to the target class, so that tooltip docs are available in Visual Studio?

Here's a basic example (configured as described in [TypeLite quickstart](http://type.litesolutions.net/Tutorials)):

```
public class Poco
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Documentation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Remarks.
    /// </remarks>
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which generates the following:

```
interface Poco {
    Name: string;
}
```

But I want:

```
interface Poco {
    /**
     * Documentation.
     * 
     * Remarks.
     */
    Name: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeLite supports generation of JDoc comments from Xml comments in C# classes. You need to call the `WithJSDoc()` fluent configuration method.

```
<#
    var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
        .WithReference("Enums.ts")
        .WithJSDoc();
#>
```

It requires XML files with documentation to be generated alongside your binaries.

[image: project configuration]

This feature isn't supported in .NET portable projects.